# Image does not display in WinUI3 XAML

Tags: xaml, winui-3

I am trying to add a picture to my Window in WinUI3 and the image is never rendered. When checking in the live visual tree, the actual size of the image is 0 even though its width and height are set to 200px. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my XAML ?

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="ClientWinUI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ClientWinUI"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    >
    
    <Grid Background="#FF494A51">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Stretch="Fill"  Width="200" Height="200" Source="Images/logo.png"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug. I was debugging the package itself and I needed to add the image to the assets found in the package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Right-click the file and open it's Properties. Set the "Copy to Output Directory" setting to either "Copy Always" or "Copy if Newer."